# How does a stock go from $173,000,000,000 per share to $0.11?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation, dilution

Investing noob here.

TOPS stock (TOP Ships Inc) on the NASDAQ is currently trading at $0.11 per share but it used to be billions per share.

Did they continuously raise so much capital that investors kept getting diluted? Is this a result of stock splitting? I really cannot fathom that stock's early valuation.

Could such a monumental plunge happen to current high value stocks such as Amazon, Tesla, or BRK.A?

Comment: Interesting that there is pretty much zero information about that company on the web which is not related to their stock. Looks like an investment scam.

Comment: googling finds this: https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/g0q5kh/what_happened_to_top_ships_stock_tops/

Comment: @Philipp Their website (https://www.topships.org/) is one of the most impressive scam websites I've ever seen. They list their management team, contact numbers, and everything. I guess if a middle-man is raking in millions then spending some dough on the site is a worthwhile investment. Seems like a pure gambling penny stock; more volatile than SPXS and SPXL.

Comment: Note that the millions or billions per share you currently see on historical price charts represent split-adjusted prices. The (old) shares of TOPS have probably never traded on NASDAQ at millions or billions per share.

Comment: @Flux I see, so splits and reverse splits are reflected on all historical data?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Splits are reflected on all historical data.  However, an occasional charting site gives you the option to look at unadjusted data.

Comment: @BobBaerker All things considered, reflecting splits on all historical data definitely makes the most sense.

Comment: Just for all those claiming the company is an investment scam they are a shipping company listed in Lloyd's registry so they have at least one ship which is both fully insured and transporting goods, which is required to be on that list. The only free source I can find is https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL1142376/Top-Ships-posts-largest-first-half-profit-since-2005

Comment: @MD-Tech Because a business listed on a registry has ever been a front or anything bad in the history of history... How much of your money have you lost in TOPS at this point?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have never invested anything in TOPS, I hadn't heard of them until this question, I just looked them up, found they were a shipping company so checked Lloyds. There is certain due diligence that Lloyds do before a company appears on the register but I won't claim that it is enough not to be a scam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's even worse than you think.  The high price for TOPS in 2004 was $173,502,005,248

The reason for this absurd price is that TOPS has had many, many reverse splits.  Here are the ones since 2008:

- 03/20/2008 1 for 3
- 06/24/2011 1 for 10
- 04/21/2014 1 for 7
- 02/22/2016 1 for 10
- 05/11/2017 1 for 20
- 06/23/2017 1 for 15
- 08/03/2017 1 for 30
- 10/06/2017 1 for 2
- 03/26/2018 1 for 10
- 08/22/2019 1 for 20

If you hypothetically owned 7,560,000,000 shares at the outset, after all of these reverse splits, you'd own one share.

Comment: Wow, nice! May I ask where you found this data?

Comment: So is this stock nothing more than a scheme to make amateur traders think the stock is skyrocketing so people jump on the bandwagon while the string-pullers sell off?

Comment: Having seen this many times over the years, I knew that the cause was reverse splits.  Then, it was just a matter of googling "TOPS reverse split history".  The first one on the list showed 9 splits.  It's not a scheme at all.   It's just a function of how data is adjusted when stock splits occur.

Comment: Why is it that we have to rely on a website like https://www.splithistory.com/ for this data? Wouldn't the SEC have some sort of formal history data? Or maybe a major broker such as Fidelity?

Comment: And the reason for the absurd price is that before 2018 the company only had a few thousand shares (I can't find the exact numbers). So "owning 756 million shares at the outset" would not be possible; you would have needed to own the entire company thousands of times over.

Comment: Owning  766 million shares was not possible nor was it possible for a share to trade at  $173,502,005,248.  This is all a function  adjusted data due to 9 reverse splits.

Comment: Could it be part of something like a money laundering or tax evasion scheme? Perhaps there's some organization that needs to send money away discreetly, and the way they do it is by "investing" the money in TOPS. The money goes directly to TOPS itself (since it's issuing new shares), and the IRS thinks that the first organization simply made a bad investment and suffered a capital loss.

Comment: 08/10/2020 1 for 25

Comment: I've edited your answer because you missed the 1 for 10 reverse split in 2011. References: [TOP Ships Inc. Announces Reverse Stock Split to be Effective June 24, 2011](https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2011/06/23/449982/225062/en/TOP-Ships-Inc-Announces-Reverse-Stock-Split-to-be-Effective-June-24-2011.html) ([Form 6-K](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1296484/000117184311003402/0001171843-11-003402-index.html)).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You can get stock split history on FINRA's [Market Data Center](https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/MarketData/Default.jsp). Enter "TOPS" in the search box, then click on the "Performance" tab where you can see the split history for TOPS ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkjYx.png)).

Comment: Another reverse split on 2022-09-23: 1 for 20